# I'm trying to call a method through a for loop, and the first iteration will only read the first line of code in the method

Tags: java, for-loop, oop, foreach, iteration

I'm trying to use an enhanced for loop to call a method many times in a row, but if I'm iterating more than once, the first iteration will only read the first line of code. Here are both of the methods I'm using:

```
public Account() {

    this.subDetails = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    
    System.out.println("What is the account type? (Individual/Family)");
    String planType = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter your card number: ");
    this.cardNum = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the expiration date: ");
    this.cardExp = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    if (planType.equals("Family")) {
        System.out.println("How many users?");
        int numUsers = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int z=0; z<numUsers; z++) {
            this.addUser();
        }
        StreamingService.numFamUsers = StreamingService.numFamUsers + numUsers;
        StreamingService.monthlyRevenue = StreamingService.monthlyRevenue + 14.99;
        StreamingService.monthlyFamRevenue = StreamingService.monthlyFamRevenue + 14.99;
    }
    else if (planType.equals("Individual")) {
        this.addUser();
        StreamingService.numIndUsers++;
        StreamingService.monthlyRevenue = StreamingService.monthlyRevenue + 9.99;
        StreamingService.monthlyIndRevenue = StreamingService.monthlyIndRevenue + 9.99;
    }
    StreamingService.numAccounts++;
    this.subDetails.put(i, planType);
    i++;

}


public void addUser() {
        System.out.println("What is the email of the next user?");
        String e = keyboard.nextLine();
        User y = new User(e, i);
        StreamingService.userEmails.add(y);
        StreamingService.numUsers++;
        this.acctUsers.add(e);
}
```

And here is the output (Data quality is poor, just used as an example):

> What is the account type? (Individual/Family)
>
> Individual
>
> Enter your card number:
>
> 1234123412341234
>
> Enter the expiration date:
>
> 02/24
>
> What is the email of the next user?
>
> abc@def.com
>
> What is the account type? (Individual/Family)
>
> Family
>
> Enter your card number:
>
> 1234123412341234
>
> Enter the expiration date:
>
> 02/24
>
> How many users?
>
> 3
>
> What is the email of the next user? What is the email of the next
> user?
>
> abc@def.com
>
> What is the email of the next user?
>
> abc@defg.com
>
> What is the account type? (Individual/Family)
>
> Family
>
> Enter your card number:
>
> 1234123412341234
>
> Enter the expiration date:
>
> 02/24
>
> How many users?
>
> 2
>
> What is the email of the next user? What is the email of the next
> user?
>
> xyz@abc.com

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What's `keyboard`? I don't see  the declaration of that varialbe in your code. By the methods you call on it, I do get that it is of type `Scanner`?

Comment: Yes, this is a scanner ^^

Comment: Yes, but how do you instanciate it? The only way your code does not do what you expect it to do is either the scanner providing a value of one for your `numUsers`, or (and the duplicate output of "What is the email of the next user?" hints towards that) will return immediately instead of waiting for the first value.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt` does NOT consume the newline-charakter you enter after the nubmers. Because of this, any readline afterwards will consume the newline - and stop, becasue that's what it does.

Because of this, the first email prompt after entering the number of users will always return an empty string. You can see this in your output: it's the cases where the email prompt is duplicated.

To fix this, put a call to `keyboard.nextLine()` after all of your `keyboard.nextInt()` calls (and just ignore the output of that function).